# How to show multiple matches in the same row separated by comma in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

got a problem with showing any matching value the same row as my lookup value, so i.e.

my first table:

| some_primary_key |
| --- |
| unique_value_1 |
| unique_value_2 |
| unique_value_3 |

other table:

| some_primary_key | values |
| --- | --- |
| unique_value_1 | some_value_1 |
| unique_value_1 | some_value_2 |
| unique_value_2 | some_value_3 |
| unique_value_2 | some_value_4 |
| unique_value_3 | some_value_5 |
| unique_value_3 | some_value_6 |

and finally I'd like to have this:

| some_primary_key | values |
| --- | --- |
| unique_value_1 | some_value_1, some_value_2 |
| unique_value_2 | some_value_3, some_value_4 |
| unique_value_3 | some_value_5, some_value_6 |

Should I use list comprehension iterating through df items and create list of lists of matching values? Any ideas?

Answer:

It is my sample solution:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'some_primary_key':['unique_value_1',
                            'unique_value_2',
                            'unique_value_3']*2,
        'values':['some_value_1', 'some_value_3', 'some_value_5',
                  'some_value_2', 'some_value_4', 'some_value_6']
                      }
                                                                          
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)


list_of_values = []
for item in df['some_primary_key']:
    filtered_values = df[df['some_primary_key']==item]
    list_of_values.append(','.join(x for x in filtered_values['values']))

df['values'] = list_of_values
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print(df)
```

Any other, neat solutions? :)

Comment: Hi @qrzep, I just update my answer with benchmark. Have a look at that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `groupby`. You can apply any custom function with `transform` after grouping them over `some_primary_key`.

You can try this:

```
concat_func  = lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x.sort_values(ascending=True).unique()))
df['values'] = df.groupby(['some_primary_key'])['values'].transform(concat_func)
```

Then, `df` will have concatenated `values` for each `some_primary_key` which makes duplicated `values`. Therefore, just remove the duplicated rows:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

**Output:**

```
  some_primary_key                     values
0   unique_value_1  some_value_1,some_value_2
1   unique_value_2  some_value_3,some_value_4
2   unique_value_3  some_value_5,some_value_6
```

**PS:**

In `concat_func`, `sort_values()` and `unique()` methods are applied to have a nicer view and prevent occurrence of the same `values` in a row. Otherwise, if `df` is:

```
  some_primary_key        values
0   unique_value_1  some_value_1
1   unique_value_1  some_value_1
```

the output will be:

```
  some_primary_key                     values
0   unique_value_1  some_value_1,some_value_1
```

If this is the desired output just use following `concat_func`:

```
concat_func = lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible alternatives with benchmarks:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'some_primary_key':['unique_value_1', 'unique_value_2', 'unique_value_3'] * 2,
    'values':['some_value_1', 'some_value_3', 'some_value_5', 'some_value_2', 'some_value_4', 'some_value_6']
}

def func_1(df):
  return df.groupby(['some_primary_key'])['values'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x)).reset_index()

def func_2(df):
  return df.groupby(['some_primary_key'])['values'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()

def func_3(df):
  return df.groupby('some_primary_key')['values'].apply(', '.join)

def func_4(df):
  return df.groupby('some_primary_key')['values'].agg(', '.join)

def func_5(df):
  return df.groupby(['some_primary_key'], as_index = False).agg({'values': ', '.join})

def func_6(df):
  return df.groupby('some_primary_key').agg({'values': ', '.join}).reset_index()

def func_7(df):
  concat_func  = lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x.sort_values(ascending=True).unique()))
  df['values'] = df.groupby(['some_primary_key'])['values'].transform(concat_func)
  return df.drop_duplicates()
                                                                      
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

print('func_1(df) runtime: ', end="")
%timeit func_1(df)

# OR

print('func_2(df) runtime: ', end="")
%timeit func_2(df)

# OR

print('func_3(df) runtime: ', end="")
%timeit func_3(df)

# OR

print('func_4(df) runtime: ', end="")
%timeit func_4(df)

# OR

print('func_5(df) runtime: ', end="")
%timeit func_5(df)

# OR

print('func_6(df) runtime: ', end="")
%timeit func_6(df)

# OR

print('func_7(df) runtime: ', end="")
%timeit func_7(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  some_primary_key                     values
0   unique_value_1  some_value_1, some_value_2
1   unique_value_2  some_value_3, some_value_4
2   unique_value_3  some_value_5, some_value_6
```

**Benchmark Output:**

```
func_1(df) runtime: 100 loops, best of 5: 1.95 ms per loop
func_2(df) runtime: 100 loops, best of 5: 2.11 ms per loop
func_3(df) runtime: 1000 loops, best of 5: 1.01 ms per loop
func_4(df) runtime: 1000 loops, best of 5: 1.18 ms per loop
func_5(df) runtime: 100 loops, best of 5: 2.86 ms per loop
func_6(df) runtime: 100 loops, best of 5: 2.46 ms per loop
func_7(df) runtime: 100 loops, best of 5: 5.01 ms per loop
```

Comment: Great! I think it is worth mentioning that the 3rd and 4th returns pd.series - others returns df.

Comment: Good suggestion. I will add that. Please give an upvote if you like my answer. :)

Comment: I'm a newbie, so I don't have enough reputation :( but I'll definitely give you an upvote when I get my rep points :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. :)